# Deploy two versions of JS in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I've read that it's possible to configure WebPack to create two bundles of JS. One of them will be for the newest browsers and inserted with `module` flag, another one is for old ones which is "translated" into ES5. Is here any built-in option to make it in Angular CLI? It would decrease the file size for users of modern browsers and wouldn't affect those who use older versions.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the article you read?

Comment: Unfortunately, it was long time ago, but I've found similar to that I've read https://gist.github.com/newyankeecodeshop/79f3e1348a09583faf62ed55b58d09d9